# Filtering Data Table with two models in single view using multiple dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I started to created my project using MVC and it's really enjoying to create different projects using mvc.

So I created awhile ago the data table that filters data when you selected value in single dropdown

But I'm still curious about filtering data using multiple dropdown and two models in a single view

What I did... first, I created a class that I can be used to display my two data table using two models

This is my class in mvc

```
 public class MyData
  {
    public IEnumerable<pmTA_ProjectCategory> ProjectCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<pmTA_FundCategory> FundCategory { get; set; }
  }
```

After creating my class, I created a code for two data table using one view for Index and view for partial view to call the two data table

this is the codes for view of Index and view of Partial View which the name is "MyPartialView"

For view of Index:

```
  @using myProject.Models;
  @model MyData


  <div id="myPartialView">
   @Html.Partial("MyPartialView",Model)
  </div>

  @if (Model.ProjectCategory != null) {
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>title </th>
        <th>
            description
        </th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ProjectCategory)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
 </table>
}
```

For view of Partial View

```
      <table id="myDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>code</th>
            <th>
                title
            </th>
            <th>
                description
            </th>
            <th>--</th>
            <th>--</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.FundCategory)

        {
            string selectedRow = "";
            if (item.id == ViewBag.fund)
            {
                selectedRow = "success";
            }
            <tr class="@selectedRow">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.code)
                </td>
                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "FundCategoryEdit", new { id = 
          item.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { 
            fund_category_id = item.id }, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
       </table>
```

Inorder to Function my view I created codes in controller to display two data table, I declared the name of my class in the controller

this the codes in my controller, the first code is for the partial view datatable and the second code is for the View Index

for partial:

```
      var viewModel = new MyData();
        viewModel.FundCategory = (from p in db.pmTA_FundCategory

                                  select new
                                  {
                                      id = p.id,
                                      code = p.code,
                                      title = p.title,
                                      description = p.description,
                                      status = p.status
                                  }).ToList()
                  .Select(x => new pmTA_FundCategory()
                  {
                      id = x.id,
                      code = x.code,
                      title = x.title,
                      description = x.description,
                      status = x.status
                  });
```

---

For View of Index

```
    if (fund_category_id != null)
        {

            ViewBag.fund = fund_category_id.Value;
            viewModel.ProjectCategory = (from p in db.pmTA_ProjectCategory
                          join g in db.pmTA_FundCategory
                           on p.fund_category_id equals g.id
                          where p.fund_category_id == fund_category_id
                          select new
                          {
                              id = p.id,
                              title = p.title,
                              description = p.description,
                              title1 = g.title,
                              status = p.status
                          }).ToList()
               .Select(x => new pmTA_ProjectCategory()
               {
                   id = x.id,
                   title = x.title,
                   description = x.description,
                   title1 = x.title1,
                   status = x.status

               });

        }

        return View(viewModel);
```

They are together in the Index controller but I seperated it in order you to understand my codes

The purpose of the if condition there is for the displaying of my View Index Data table when click the "Select" button of the partial data table based on there ID, you can use the codes above as your reference for showing another data table using other data table...

To display my multiple drop down I always used this codes

Codes for View of Index to display dropdowns

```
     <div>
     @Html.DropDownList("id", ViewBag.funds as SelectList, "Select...", new 
     { @class = "form-control" })
     </div>
     <div>
     @Html.DropDownList("projectcat", ViewBag.proj as SelectList, 
    "Select...", new 
     { @class = "form-control" })
      </div>
```

Codes for dropdown in controller to display the data inside of it based on the database data

for first and second dropdown

```
     var data1 = from p in db.pmTA_FundCategory

                    select new
                    {
                        id = p.id,
                        code = p.code,
                        title = p.title,
                        description = p.description
                    };

        SelectList list = new SelectList(data1, "id", "title");
         ViewBag.funds = list;
```

---

```
     var data2 = from p in db.pmTA_ProjectCategory

                    select new
                    {
                        id = p.id,
                        title = p.title,
                        description = p.description
                    };

        SelectList list1 = new SelectList(data2, "id", "title");
        ViewBag.proj = list1;
```

The problem is... How I gonna filter my Partial Data table using multiple drop down without using any plugins but with the help of javascript or any method to filter the data of data table?

Once I selected the value of my multiple dropdown my Partial Data table will display the data corresponds to the multiple dropdown selected...

Comment: you have to display `ProjectCategory` in main view and `FundCategory` in partial view right?

Comment: you have to filter `ProjectCategory` data table with one drop down and other `FundCategory` data table with another drop down. means no any relation between both data table means when i changed option from first drop down then only `ProjectCategory` data table will be filter without any effect on other `FundCategory` data table and vice versa. let me know so I'll add an answer.

Comment: in terms of filtering data table to another data table I dont have any concern,  my only concern is filtering of my datatable in PArtial using multiple dropdowns

Comment: my data table of partial and data table in the view of my index has no issues

Comment: does it good for you that both table are in partial view?

Comment: its ok with me... if that's the only way I can filter my data table in my partial

Comment: you can filter in both means in partial and in view also. but if u use partial then only part of that view will be refreshed and in case of view then need to refresh full view and its not efficient way.

Comment: if that is the case what do you think should I do ?

Comment: if you want to build your app with more efficiency and you want your app will be more elegant then you should go with partial otherwise view.

Comment: I tried to do that...  same partial view of my data table it function smoothly ... my problem is my filtering its hard to filter using two models in single view, even your codes that i used a while ago I still get errors when I apply to my single view using two models

Comment: which error did u faced? bcoz when i implement my side it does not gave me any error

Comment: Filtering my data table in my Partial View using multiple drop down using my two models in my single view which my single view , viewed my partial because I call it in my View Index

Comment: any specific error or exception, so text here

Comment: what I mean in your codes is that I gets error when I revised my data table because I used two models this time , your codes functions if you just used single model and single drop down ... but what I did now is I added two models and multiple dropdown

Comment: using this codes that you gave me I can't apply to multiple model because I create a class that I can used to display my to models ... this is the code List<SelectListItem> dropDownItems = charts.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.title, Value = c.id.ToString() }).ToList();
            ViewBag.proj = dropDownItems;  and your javascript before because it not suit for multiple dropdown ...

Comment: let me know, you followed same steps for your second drop down that is in my previous answer. bcoz now i implemented multiple drop down and it doesn't give me any error and it working good

Comment: Can I ask you a favor? Can you give me sample of javascript like you give me a while a ago ...  you said it doesn't give you error maybe I used that as my reference ... please

Comment: hard to add in comment so i added it in answer

Comment: can i ask a question ? sorry ... where do I find the answer in stackoverflow ? when I refreshes my browser I can't find it ...sorry

Comment: not added yet but you will find answer in below of your question

Comment: Ok :) thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multiple Table with Multiple Drop Down**

1) Add two drop down in your main view like

```
<div class="dropdown">
    @Html.DropDownList("id", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.proj, "--Select id--", new { @onchange = "CallChangefunc1(this.value)" })
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
    @Html.DropDownList("id", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.funds, "--Select id--", new { @onchange = "CallChangefunc2(this.value)" })
</div>
```

2) Add two partial view 1st with name `_GetProjectCategory.cshtml` and 2nd with name `_GetFundCategory.cshtml`

Make sure that

1st partial view `@model` will be of type `@model IEnumerable<WebApplicationMVC1.Controllers.ProjectCategory>`

2nd partial view `@model` will be of type `@model IEnumerable<WebApplicationMVC1.Controllers.FundCategory>`

Simply add your content in respective partial view.

Make sure both of your partial view contains.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { //You table contents }
```

3) Call both partial view in your main view like

```
<div id="myPartialView1">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_GetProjectCategory", Model.ProjectCategories);}
</div>

<div id="myPartialView2">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_GetFundCategory", Model.FundCategories);}
</div>
```

4) Then create a view model like

```
public class ProjectFundViewModel
{
    public List<ProjectCategory> ProjectCategories { get; set; }
    public List<FundCategory> FundCategories { get; set; }
}
```

5) Your action method will be (Its sample code and replace by your code).

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //The below query replace by yours
    var projects = db.ProjectCategories.ToList();

    List<SelectListItem> dropDownItems1 = projects.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.title, Value = c.id.ToString() }).ToList();
    ViewBag.proj = dropDownItems1;

    //The below query replace by yours
    var funds = db.FundCategories.ToList();

    List<SelectListItem> dropDownItems2 = funds.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.title, Value = c.id.ToString() }).ToList();
    ViewBag.funds = dropDownItems2;

    ProjectFundViewModel viewModel = new ProjectFundViewModel
    {
        ProjectCategories = projects,
        FundCategories = funds
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

6) Add ajax call to your main view that called when you change any option in respective drop down

```
<script>

    function CallChangefunc1(id) {
         $.ajax({
             url: "@Url.Action("GetProjectCategory", "Default")",
             data: { id: id },
            type: "Get",
            dataType: "html",    
             success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
                //Whatever result you have got from your controller with html partial view replace with a specific html.
                $("#myPartialView1").html( data ); // HTML DOM replace
            }
        });
    }

    function CallChangefunc2(id) {
         $.ajax({
             url: "@Url.Action("GetFundCategory", "Default")",
             data: { id: id },
            type: "Get",
            dataType: "html",    
             success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
                //Whatever result you have got from your controller with html partial view replace with a specific html.
                $("#myPartialView2").html( data ); // HTML DOM replace
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

7) And finally your ajax call hit below action method that can render respective partial view.

```
public PartialViewResult GetProjectCategory(int id)
{
    var projects = db.ProjectCategories.ToList();
    var model = projects.Where(x => x.id == id).ToList();
    return PartialView("_GetProjectCategory", model);
}

public PartialViewResult GetFundCategory(int id)
{
    var funds = db.FundCategories.ToList();
    var model = funds.Where(x => x.id == id).ToList();
    return PartialView("_GetFundCategory", model);
}
```

8) Make sure your main view `@model` is `@model WebApplicationMVC1.Controllers.ProjectFundViewModel` not `IEnumerable`.

**Single Table with Multiple Drop Down**

1) Add two drop down in your main view with id

```
<div class="dropdown">
    @Html.DropDownList("id", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ids, "--Select id--", new { @onchange = "CallChangefunc1(this.value)", @id = "dropdown1" })
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
    @Html.DropDownList("title", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.titles, "--Select title--", new { @onchange = "CallChangefunc2(this.value)", @id = "dropdown2" })
</div>
```

2) Add partial view with name `GetFilteredData.cshtml` with model `@model IEnumerable<WebApplicationMVC1.Controllers.ProjectCategory>`.

Make sure your partial view contains.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { //You table contents }
```

3) Call your partial view in main view like

```
<div id="myPartialView">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("GetFilteredData", Model.ProjectCategories);}
</div>
```

4) Now your first drop down contains `ids` and second drop down contains `titles` from projects category.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var projects = db.ProjectCategories.ToList();

    List<SelectListItem> dropDownItems1 = projects.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.id.ToString(), Value = c.id.ToString() }).ToList();
    ViewBag.ids = dropDownItems1;

    List<SelectListItem> dropDownItems2 = projects.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.title, Value = c.title }).ToList();
    ViewBag.titles = dropDownItems2;

    ProjectFundViewModel viewModel = new ProjectFundViewModel
    {
        ProjectCategories = projects,
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

5) Add ajax call from main view like

```
<script>

    function CallChangefunc1(id) {

        var title = $("#dropdown2").val();

         $.ajax({
             url: "@Url.Action("GetFilteredData", "Default2")",
             data: { id: id, title: title },
            type: "Get",
            dataType: "html",
             success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
                //Whatever result you have got from your controller with html partial view replace with a specific html.
                 $("#myPartialView").html( data ); // HTML DOM replace
            }
        });
    }

    function CallChangefunc2(title) {

        var id = $("#dropdown1").val();

         $.ajax({
             url: "@Url.Action("GetFilteredData", "Default2")",
             data: { id: id, title: title },
            type: "Get",
            dataType: "html",
             success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
                //Whatever result you have got from your controller with html partial view replace with a specific html.
                 $("#myPartialView").html( data ); // HTML DOM replace
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

6) And finally your ajax call hit below action method with 2 parameters.

```
public PartialViewResult GetFilteredData(int? id, string title)
{
    var query = db.ProjectCategories.ToList();

    if (id != null)
        query = query.Where(x => x.id == id).ToList();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
        query = query.Where(x => x.title == title).ToList();

    return PartialView("GetFilteredData", query);
}
```

Comment: @Eemq07, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: thank you for your codes,  but what I want to do is just one data table must filtered by multiple dropdown what you did is two data table filtered by different two drop down ...  but I tried your codes and it functions

Comment: I'll just show two table ... to show that I used two models in single view and the class that I created because my intention is to use this code var viewModel = new MyData(); to get two models

Comment: but I will used some of your codes cause i think this will help me  ProjectFundViewModel viewModel = new ProjectFundViewModel
    {
        ProjectCategories = projects,
        FundCategories = funds
    };

Comment: by your comment above => `I want to do is just one data table must filtered by multiple dropdown `. I'll update the answer soon...

Comment: let me know you want immediate result after selecting both drop down, means if i select option from 1st drop down then its result will appear immediately or selecting option from both of drop down and then result will appear?

Comment: it works I used some of your code ... thank you again for your help :) ... I tested it now

Comment: can I ask you something? what is the purpose of id in the codes function CallChangefunc2(id) { ... Is it the name of the dropdown?

Comment: When you select any option from drop down then its selected value pass to this function as a parameter and then we forward that id  to action  method to get particular record from db.

Comment: @Eemq07, view the section **Single Table with Multiple Drop Down** in answer might be it help you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195486/button-select-to-filter-datable-to-another-datatable-using-two-model-in-single... can you help me again about my concern